# Magento2: How to get current product category id?

Tags: magento2, product, category, knockoutjs

I want to get the current product category ids by Knockout JS.

Please help.

Comment: where you want to get? In your custom module?

Comment: Yes, my custom module. I want to get the current product category on the product page. @RohanHapani

Comment: Please check my previous question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/305223/magento2-how-to-get-cart-product-category-ids-by-knockout-js @RohanHapani

Comment: Please check : https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-get-categories-specific-product-magento-2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all category ids of current product with Knockout in your custom module using following way:

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Product" name="index.kojs" template="Vendor_Module::catids.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Product.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    /**
     * @var array|\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessorInterface[]
     */
    protected $layoutProcessors;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductCategoryList
     */
    protected $productCategoryList;

    /**
     * [__construct description]
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context             [description]
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry                      $registry            [description]
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductCategoryList       $productCategoryList [description]
     * @param array                                            $layoutProcessors    [description]
     * @param array                                            $data                [description]
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductCategoryList $productCategoryList,
        array $layoutProcessors = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->jsLayout = isset($data['jsLayout']) && is_array($data['jsLayout']) ? $data['jsLayout'] : [];
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->layoutProcessors = $layoutProcessors;
        $this->productCategoryList = $productCategoryList;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getJsLayout()
    {
        foreach ($this->layoutProcessors as $processor) {
            $this->jsLayout = $processor->process($this->jsLayout);
        }
        return \Zend_Json::encode($this->jsLayout);
    }

    public function getCatIds()
    {
        $productId = $this->_registry->registry('current_product')->getId();
        $categoryIds = $this->productCategoryList->getCategoryIds($productId);
        return json_encode($categoryIds);
    }
}
```

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/catids.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Maagento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>
<div id="kocat" data-bind="scope:'kocat'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#kocat": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                    "components": {
                        "kocat": {
                            "component": "Vendor_Module/js/view/kocat",
                            "defaultCollection":<?= $block->getCatIds(); ?>
                         }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/kocat.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'mage/url',
    'mage/storage',
    'mage/validation'
], function ($,ko, Component, urlBuilder,storage) {
    'use strict';
    return Component.extend({
        /*Initialization*/
        initialize: function () {
           self = this;
           self._super();
           console.log(self.defaultCollection);
        },
    });
});
```

Check in console, you will get all category ids of current product on product page.

I hope it will helpful for you.

Comment: Please help me my previous questions https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/305223/63273

Comment: Okay, let me check it.

Comment: This is working fine.

Comment: Ok, Please check and let me know best solution for that.

Comment: Yes sure, I'll check it and let you know for the same.